# Rails 3rd party large database update without downtime

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database

Using Rails 3.2 and MySQL. I have an implementation problem:

My app database `abc` with tables `products`, `users`, etc.

3rd party database `xyz` with tables: `products`, `product_images`, etc.

1. Database `xyz` is refreshed every week by downloading from 3rd party server, and replace the existing `xyz`. This database is 2GB.
2. `xyz.products` is imported to `abc.products` for listing and searching.
3. When a row from `abc.products` is called, it would look for `xyz.product_images` to list the images.

Question: Every time `xyz` is being updated (database dumped and imported), some `abc.product_images` would not be found. How can I implement this to have no downtime on my app? Each time the `xyz` is refreshed, it takes 2-3 hours to complete.

I even thought of downloading the new `xyz` and import to `xyz_new`, import the `xyz.products` to `abc.products`, then drop `xyz` and rename `xyz_new` to `xyz`, but this itself takes a long time as MySQL doesn't have rename function.

Comment: Did you able to solve this? I am having same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the best answer, but temporarily here's my workaround:

1. `xyz` is the database to be updated regularly.
2. `abc` is the app database to be updated based on `xyz`.
3. Copy table structure of `xyz.products` to `xyz.products_new`. Import new data to it.
4. Copy table structure of `xyz.product_images` to `xyz.product_images_new`. Import new data to it.
5. Drop `xyz.products`, rename `xyz.products_new` to `xyz.products`.
6. Drop `xyz.product_images`, rename `xyz.product_images_new` to `xyz.product_images`.
7. Run script to compare `xyz.products` against `abc.proucts`. Create/delete/update if necessary.

Downtime is very minimal because I am renaming the table instead of a database.